# How to get specific row text as dataGridView Column Header text C#

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I'm trying to load csv file into dataGridView. I need to load specific row substring as dataGridView column header text. What's more i want to add columns dynamically. Here's example csv file:

```
#COLUMN1=TRUE;Data;0
#COLUMN2=TRUE;Godzina;0
#COLUMN3=TRUE;Kod zdarzenia;0
#COLUMN4=TRUE;Nazwa zdarzenia;0
```

Im reading this csv using:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string[] rows;
    rows = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
    foreach (var r in rows)
    {
        r.Split(';');
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to have e.g two dataGridViewColumns. How to add this columns dynamically e.g: I don't want to add the first three rows but only 4th and 5th row from csv file as dataGridViewColumn ?

```
#COLUMN2=TRUE;Godzina;0
#COLUMN3=TRUE;Kod zdarzenia;0
```

I'm also checking if row from CSV file StartsWith "#COLUMN". I want that dataGridColumns Header Text gets value from MIDDLE substring of row e.g Godzina.

DataGridView should looks like:

```
Godzina | Kod zdarzenia | other columns...
tmp1    | tmp2          | other values...
other rows...
```

Comment: add your datagridview codes.. Add what you've tried yet

Comment: At least tell us how you want the output to look like

Comment: What's really your question? Solving your logic problem or populating the DataGridView?

Comment: populating the dataGridView of course